# How to render html string in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm having a problem with getting HTML to render when I pull from Shopify's API. I'm able to access Shopify API, but it isn't rendering the information the right way. What happens when I access it, is I get the HTML with the tags, instead of the tags doing the formatting for me. It looks like this.

**Information Presented On Website**

```
<p class="p1"><strong>Coolin' for the season.</strong></p> <p class="p1">- True to size fit</p> <p class="p1">- Made with a Champion© 50% cotton/50% polyester hoodie.</p> <p class="p1">- Embroidered front Safe House and "Champion C logo" decoration on the cuff.</p> <p class="p1">- Wash in cold water to prevent shrinkage</p> <p class="p1"><strong>Brought to you exclusively by Safe House Chicago.</strong></p> <p class="p2"> </p> <p class="p1"><strong>*Please allow 14-21 days for delivery for your icey item.*</strong></p> <p class="p2"> </p> <p class="p1"><strong>Model is wearing a size medium</strong></p>
```

Instead of what I need

**How I want information presented**

```
Coolin' for the season.

- True to size fit

- Made with a Champion© 50% cotton/50% polyester hoodie.

- Embroidered front Safe House and "Champion C logo" decoration on the cuff.

- Wash in cold water to prevent shrinkage

Brought to you exclusively by Safe House Chicago.



*Please allow 14-21 days for delivery for your icey item.*



Model is wearing a size medium
```

Here's how my code looks (I will separate later)

**ShopProduct.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PageHeader from './PageHeader'
import { fetchSingleProduct, fetchAllProducts } from "../utils/shopifyHelpers"
import styles from '../styles';


export default class ShopProduct extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: '',
      title: '',
      productInfo: ''
    }
  }
  singleProduct(){
    let productDetails
    fetchSingleProduct('7078139269')
    .then((product) => {
      this.setState({
        productInfo: product.description
      })
    })
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.singleProduct()
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PageHeader header="Placeholder"/>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <h1 className="text-center">{this.state.title}</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <h1 className="text-center">{this.state.productInfo}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to make it properly render the information without all the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render this string in `HTML`, you need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property, try this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: a}}></div>
```

Here `a` will contain the string that you pasted in ques.

Check `jsfiddle` for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/dd1ckue2/